# Proving Jordan's curve theorem from Jordan-Schoenfliess. Boundedness

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I have an issue while proving Jordan's curve theorem from Jordan-Schoenflies theorem. I could proof that $\mathbb{R}^2 - C$ where $C$ is a Jordan curve has two connected components with frontier C. One of them is $f(int(\mathbb{S}^1))$ and the other $f(ext(\mathbb{S}^1))$.

However how do i proof boundedness? I'd say $f(int(\mathbb{S}^1))$ is bounded since it is in a compact set what about $f(ext(\mathbb{S}^1))$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(ext(\mathbb{S}^1))$ is not bounded. If it were, then $\mathbb{R}^2$ would be a union of three bounded sets, hence $\mathbb{R}^2$ would be bounded.